# How to use a hover css pseudo to apply only to the top level element?

Tags: css

if i was to have the following HTML:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        "I want to access this div and change the background colour on a hover"
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

how do i access the top level div to apply styles to it without affecting the parent divs?

**NB** - *it is for a general system where div's are dynamically generated, therefore adding a class or id is not a solution to this particular problem.*

Comment: If the divs are dynamically generated, can't you just dynamically generate the top level one with a class or ID?

Comment: not really as there will be a number of siblings to the divs as well so I'm really looking for some sort psudo selector that will get the top level divs without the use of classes or ids

Comment: You can do it if all your top level divs are in a container. **Why can't you just give them a class in whatever generates them?**

Comment: "it is for a general system where div's are dynamically generated, therefore adding a class or id is not a solution to this particular problem" - why in the world would that be the case? If you don't have control over the html generation that's one thing, but if you do then you are making a very easy problem much harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is you're out of luck.

There is no CSS3 selector for "an element that does not contain child elements, only text".

Comment: I have to agree, there is no valid solution using just css and html. Code rewrite here i come...

Comment: I think in the future when CSS Selectors Level 4 is a bit more supported, something like this might work: `:hover:not(:has(*))` ("if I'm being hovered and I don't have any child elements").

Answer (score 0):

If the div is directly inside `<body>` just doing this is fine:

```
div {
    /* Styles */
}
```

If it's not, give it an ID (if there's only one of these such divs) or a class if there are multiple:

```
<div id="foo">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        "I want to access this div and change the background colour on a hover"
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then select it like:

```
div#foo {
    /* Styles */
}
```

You haven't given any context in your OP, so this is a general solution.

Comment: its for a very general system where divs are dynamically generated, so theres no knowing how many there will be. I need to access only the div sitting at the top without affecting the parents of it. div { styles } will access all of the divs

Answer (score 0):

To change the background colour of the 4th div, when hovering over the 1st div:

```
div:hover div div div {
    background-color: #some_color;
}
```

Comment: sorry, have slightly modified the question to be more specific, there will not necessarily be 4 divs

Comment: ah now I see that I misunderstood your initial question. If it's possible to add an ID or class to the last div, you can go with @JamWaffles solution, accessing the div by it's id `#foo` or class `.foo`.

Answer (score 0):

What i came up was undoing everything you to do the first div to the last div generated. Here is a jsFiddle thing you can play around with: http://jsfiddle.net/ns6PS/
HTML:

```
<div> <div> <div> <div>
   "I want to access this div and change the background colour on a hover"
</div> </div> </div> </div>
css:
div { background-color: #ddd;    }
div div div div { background-color: #fff; }
```

correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: As mentioned in a comment on another answer, there may not necessarily be four `div` elements, there may be more or less.

Comment: you can always use javascript to get the all the div.

Comment: how about .../div:first-child { ... some amazing css ... }
div:first-child {
 background: #ddd;   
}
div:last-child {
  background: #fff;   
}

Comment: That selects all the `div`s in the example, because all of them are first children.

Comment: Sigh. All of the `div`s are both the first and last children, so again your fiddle doesn't do what you're thinking.

Comment: oh okay i see what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').on('mouseover.mainfunction', function() {
    return false;
});
```

Will cause the event to only shoot on the topmost div
so... div:hover will only apply to that div.

That's the jQuery version.